# reshape::recast won't use fill=NA for sum

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

```
a <- data.frame(
variable=c("a","b","c"),
date=c("2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-02"),
value=c(1,2,3))
```

I get

```
recast(a,date~variable,sum,fill=10000)
Using variable, date as id variables
>        date     a     b     c
>1 2015-01-01     1     2 10000
>2 2015-01-02 10000 10000     3
```

but

```
recast(a,date~variable,sum,fill=NA)
Using variable, date as id variables
```

> Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be type 'logical',
>    but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'

why is that so ?

From the help

> fill : value with which to fill in structural missings, defaults to value from applying fun.aggregate to 0 length vector

In that case I would like the `sum` to be `NA` when there are missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify what `NA` type you want to use, and it should work:

```
recast(a, date ~ variable, sum, fill = NA_real_)
# Using variable, date as id variables
#         date  a  b  c
# 1 2015-01-01  1  2 NA
# 2 2015-01-02 NA NA  3
```

Comment: Thank you ! Was scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Same thing in `reshape2::dcast`, btw